# Laying dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I would like laying my dropdown menu over the content. Now, if I click hamburger icon, whole my site go down but I want to fixed it if I click hamburger icon. Whether I use z-index or something else?

Look on my screenshots:

*before click*

[image: before click]

*after click*

[image: after click]

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

ul {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #d2141a;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  border-top: 4px solid #f4363c;
}

ul,
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c1030a;
}

ul,
li:hover {
  background-color: #c1030a;
}

ul,
li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #c72c1b;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <i class="fas fa-bars">A</i>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Restaurant</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Progress</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `nav{position:absolute}`

Comment: It works! Oh dear, only one line :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add:

```
nav{position:absolute}
```